# Condo fan coil thermostat fan never turns off, cooling is humid

Tags: hvac, thermostat, fans, humidity

My thermostat in my condo is a honeywell thermostat and it the only options it has are System and Fan. Fan is set to auto (other option is Lo Med Hi) and the System is set to Cool (or Auto or Off). When it reaches the desired temperature it does not turn off the fan but instead turns it down to Lo speed but keeps running. I notice that at this point it pumps humid air into the unit so my only options are to make it freezing cold so it never turns off cooling or to turn it off completely from fuse. Otherwise it will be humid 24/7. Should note that when System is set to OFF the fan is still running at Lo unless you pull the fuse. How can I fix this?

The tray is empty and not filled with water (someone told me that it could be humid because water isnt draining), the fan coils are dirty but it just looks some a bit of dust (this problem existed for the past 2 years and the fan coil is 2 years old so if it was a dust problem it wouldn't have existed earlier too.)

Furthermore it appears that the A/C is too big for the unit since it can get it from 30 down to 20 in 30 mins or less and constantly turns off cooling when it reaches the temp you set it too very fast.

[image: pic1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

EDIT: Added images

Keep in mind in the first image R and RC have this metal loop connecting them and the wire is in RC.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring diagram and the actual thermostat wiring at your fan coil?

Comment: What model is the thermostat?  My thought is a setting is wrong in the thermostat.  Wiring diagram and model numbers of the unit and we can get started in assisting.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Added pictures!

Comment: @user68386 Added pictures!

Comment: @Siphonophorae -- we need photos of the fan coil unit itself -- both its wiring compartment and its wiring diagram (which should be posted on the unit)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Do you mean you want me to unscrew the protector behind the filter and take a photo of the wires behind it?

Comment: @Siphonophorae yes, there should also be a label on the air handler/fan-coil unit with the wiring diagram on it.  (it may be inside the wiring compartment)

Comment: Thanks. They help a bit. As mentioned also a pic of the thermostat wire terminations in the fan coil unit to verify they match what is in the thermostat.    Here is a link to the manual for the thermostat.   https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://customer.honeywell.com/request.cfm%3Fform%3D63-2675&ved=2ahUKEwic2oLRzMnjAhWmiOAKHctZC20QFjAAegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw0Y0efjntC4L6Iil1hefobv       . My thought about a setting being wrong is looking more likely.  System settings for that fan coil should be set for a 4 pipe fan coil(0170 setting as number 7). Other settings to check are

Comment: 0347 and 0348 which should be set to 1. Every unit in the building has the same thermostats. Building management might help by switching the thermostat with another.

Comment: @user68386 Thank you I'll check that out soon. I should note that after speaking to management they said every unit in the building is designed so the fan never turns off as part of something to do with power saving and pressurization. But this doesn't explain the humidity (I discussed with a neighbour and they did not have a humidity problem). Does this help at all to finding the problem?

Comment: Power savings and pressurization?  Yeah , right!  Is your hydro included in the maintenance fees? And I don't see how circulating air in the unit changes pressure. Condos are designed to breathe hense the air leakage at the suite door.  Back to the problem...  looks like you get to try your hand at the settings as management will not help. The instructions in the manual that I linked earlier will help. So long as the system matches the unit in setting 0170, the rest that are still available are user preference.